# I can't get all the page data or Trendyol.com blocks me as a bot - Scrapping

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, request

I get with links.json links and collect data back to data.json, but I can't get all the sizes of the product, only 1 size passes, the one that is selected by default

I tried selenium there is the same, all the other data I get is fine, only I can't get the sizes
pls any help me

I get with links.json links and collect data back to data.json, but I can't get all the sizes of the product, only 1 size passes, the one that is selected by default

I tried selenium there is the same, all the other data I get is fine, only I can't get the sizes
pls any help me

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re
import math
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
import os

# Парсер для сайта Trendyol.com

with open('links.json') as file:
    links = json.load(file)


def parsingHtml(items):
    productsData = []
    id = 1
    total = len(items)
    for link in items:

        # Получаем данные о товаре
        html = r.get(link).text
        singleDocument = bs(html, 'html.parser')

        # title
        if singleDocument.select_one('h1'):
            title = singleDocument.select_one('h1').text

        # brand
        brand = ''
        if singleDocument.select_one('h1 a'):
            brand = singleDocument.select_one('h1 a').text
            brand = brand.split(' ')
            brand = '-'.join(brand).lower()

        # categories
        if singleDocument.select('.product-detail-breadcrumb span'):
            categories = singleDocument.select(
                '.product-detail-breadcrumb span')
            categories = [category.text for category in categories]
            if 'Kadın' in categories:
                categories = 'kadin'
            elif 'Erkek' in categories:
                categories = 'erkek'

        # imgs
        if singleDocument.select('.product-slide img'):
            imgs = singleDocument.select('.product-slide img')
            if(len(imgs) > 0):
                img1 = imgs[0].get('src')
                img1 = re.sub('mnresize/128/192/', '', img1)
            if(len(imgs) > 1):
                img2 = imgs[1].get('src')
                img2 = re.sub('mnresize/128/192/', '', img2)
        else:
            if(singleDocument.select_one('.detail-section-img')):
                img1 = singleDocument.select_one('.detail-section-img')
                img1 = img1.get('src')
                img2 = ''

        # price 599,95
        price = 0
        if singleDocument.select_one('span.prc-org'):
            price = singleDocument.select_one('span.prc-org').text
        else:
            price = singleDocument.select_one('span.prc-dsc').text

        price = price.split(' ')[0]
        price = re.sub(',', '.', price)
        price = math.ceil(float(price))

        # price TL to COM converting
        price = str(math.ceil(((price * 2) / 17.3 + 5) * 85))

        # sizes
        if singleDocument.select('.variants'):
            sizes = singleDocument.select(
                '#product-detail-app .size-variant-wrapper .variants .sp-itm')
            sizes = [size.text for size in sizes]

        # description
        description = singleDocument.select_one('.detail-desc-list')
        description = "{description}".format(description=description)
        description = re.sub('class="detail-desc-list"', "", description)

        product = {
            'id': id,
            'title': title,
            'price': price,
            'imageUrl1': img1,
            'imageUrl2': img2,
            'category': categories,
            'description': description,
            'brand': brand,
        }
        sizes = {str(i)+'-size': sizes[i] for i in range(len(sizes))}

        product.update(sizes)
        # print(product)

        productsData.append(product)

        os.system('clear')
        print(str(id) + '/' + str(total))
        id = id + 1
    os.system('clear')
    print('DONE', len(links), 'products')
    # return productsData
    with open("data.json", "w") as outfile:
        json.dump(productsData, outfile, ensure_ascii=False)


parsingHtml(links)
```

link 1: https://www.trendyol.com/massimo-dutti/erkek-fermuarli-pamuklu-hirka-00934401-p-103760579?boutiqueId=594929&merchantId=152256

link 2: https://www.trendyol.com/massimo-dutti/blok-renkli-bisiklet-yaka-kazak-p-237719645?boutiqueId=594929&merchantId=152256

sizes but i get only first size : https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogbtr.png

Comment: can you give some examples of urls you are accessing, and cannot get the product sizes?

Comment: I replied from below as a comment

Comment: @platipus_on_fire any ideas? please take a look

Answer (score 0):

(If I understand your question correctly) additional product sizes are being generated by Javascript after html loads, so requests/BeautifulSoup doesn't see them. One way of obtaining the sizes for the product would be:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import json
headers= {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

url = 'https://www.trendyol.com/massimo-dutti/blok-renkli-bisiklet-yaka-kazak-p-237719645?boutiqueId=594929&merchantId=152256'
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
# print(soup.text)
sizes = soup.find('script', string = re.compile("__PRODUCT_DETAIL_APP_INITIAL_STATE__"))
json_object = json.loads(sizes.text.split('window.__PRODUCT_DETAIL_APP_INITIAL_STATE__=')[1].split(';window.TYPageName=')[0])
print(json_object['product']['allVariants'])
```

This returns a JSON object looking like this:

```
[{'itemNumber': 382085453, 'value': 'M', 'inStock': True, 'currency': 'TRY', 'barcode': '0098131381203', 'price': 299}, {'itemNumber': 382066339, 'value': 'L', 'inStock': False, 'currency': 'TRY', 'barcode': '0098131381204', 'price': 299}, {'itemNumber': 382085450, 'value': 'XL', 'inStock': True, 'currency': 'TRY', 'barcode': '0098131381205', 'price': 299}]
```

The sizes only can be obtained like this:

```
print([x['value'] for x in json_object['product']['allVariants']])
```

Which would return a list with the sizes:

```
['M', 'L', 'XL']
```

You can extract other information from that initial json object as well.

BeautifulSoup documentation can be found at https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#